# Screen Brightness on new MacBook Pro 8,3?

Tags: hardware, macbook, brightness

2011 8,3 MacBook Pro running 64bit 11.10.

The screen brightness keys seem to actually do things, but nothing actually changes with regard to actual laptop screen brightness. (See [this video](http://youtu.be/atO7QfTUf3Q). Ubuntu can sense when the buttons are pressed, but nothing actually happens with screen brightness. I know you wouldn't be able to see it if it *did* work, but it doesn't.)

Is this a known issue? How can I adjust the screen brightness on my MacBook Pro?

I know I can do something *like* this in the AMD/ATI FGLRX configuration software, but it actually just adjusts the output picture, not the physical laptop's screen brightness. What can I do?

Comment: I opened this thread on ubuntuforums, i find it another useful place to get answers: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=11566082 The reason is i wanted the world to know i also have this problem, and that modifying the brightness file doesn't work for me also. Feel free to remove this "answer".

Comment: The reason you get "permission denied" is due to a problem in the way he wrote the script above. Try `echo 10 | sudo tee /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness`. That'll do what he's intending, but it doesn't update things for me at least.

Comment: Do you still have this problem? I'm running 12.04 on a Macbook Pro 8-2 and I can change the screen brightness using the "default" brightness media keys after a standard installation. I can change the brightness setting also by changing the value in `/sys/class/backlight/gmx_backlight/brightness`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Apparently, you need to boot to EFI, not to emulated BIOS, as is what happens with rEFIt.

Comment: Are you booting Ubuntu using UEFI now? Or have you simply given up on finding a solution :)

Comment: Yes, if you boot using OSX's native boot screen rather than rEFIt, it seems to work.

Comment: What do you mean by "it seems"... :P

Comment: It works. Period.

Comment: E.g. Does Ubuntu see your integrated graphics? If it boots using BIOS emulation, you'll only be able to use discrete graphics. That's the problem that I'm having. The battery life is therefore short and my MBP is generally hot.

Comment: It doesn't see my integrated graphics. See my post on this [here](http://blog.tkassembled.com/208/ubuntu-11-10-on-a-macbook-pro-8123/#comment-469).

Comment: Interesting to read! Thanks for that link. I've also taken a look at the instruction for EFI booting in debian (there was a link). But I'm very surprised by the ridiculous amount of tasks you have to do. Not that I would not expect that. But Arch Linux' explanations seems very short and simple in comparison! -> https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/MacBook_Pro_8,1_/_8,2_/_8,3_(2011_Macbook_Pro)

Answer (score 1):

Are you using ubuntu on mac? If yes then you can change your screen brightness using the following command:

```
echo 4 | sudo tee /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness
```

Value range: 1 to 10 [1 lowest, 10 highest]

Also you can set the brightness at start-up. Append the line in **/etc/rc.local** before **exit 0**

Comment: I don't think that does anything, actually. Here's a `tree` of the `/sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/` directory, if that helps: http://pastebin.com/gmgYmPJR

Comment: It actually does write to the files, but nothing really changes. Could there be something I need to do in Xorg?

Comment: "No such file or directory"

Answer (score 0):

I have a white MacBook running Ubuntu and the brightness keys work fine; however, it does seem to be an issue with the MacBook Pro (I don't have one handy to test on). But I did find [this](http://blog.fejes.ca/?p=510) in my search. It looks like a script that you can bind to a key event. The tutorial covers KDE, but binding a script to a key in Gnome is relatively simple as well, if I recall correctly. Does this properly address your problem?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't seem to have anything at all under `/sys/devices/virtual/backlight`. Is there a module I need? Again it's an 8,3 MBP and I'm running 11.10.

Comment: I'm having this issue too, with a white MacBook. It worked some time ago, I just notice it doesn't work anymore. It's definitely not a MBP issue. Also happens with MB White.