# MacBook Pro screen brightness adjust not working (15" mid 2014 model w/ GeForce 750M, Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS)

Tags: nvidia, brightness, macbook, backlight

**Issue**

I installed Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS on my MacBook Pro 15" Mid 2014. As many others, I can not get the brightness adjustment to work. Whenever I press the corresponding keys `F1`, `F2` the brightness adjustment does pop up and reacts, but the actual brightness of the screen always stays on max (I presume, something very bright) and does not change.

It is a fresh install and it does have a NVIDIA GeForce 750M Mac Edition.

**Not working Solutions**

So far I have tried [manually adjusting the brightness](https://askubuntu.com/questions/90640/screen-brightness-on-new-macbook-pro-8-3) via

```
echo 4 | sudo tee /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness
```

which did not work.

I have also tried adding

```
setpci -v -H1 -s 00:01.00 BRIDGE_CONTROL=0
```

to `/etc/rs.local` as suggested [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/812734/macbook-pro-backlight-control-not-working-on-ubuntu-16-04/1277326#1277326) after [creating `rs.local`](https://vpsfix.com/community/server-administration/no-etc-rc-local-file-on-ubuntu-18-04-heres-what-to-do/), because it wasn't present in the first place.

Lastly I tried adding

```
Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device0"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    BoardName      "GeForce 750M Mac Edition"
    Option         "RegistryDwords" "EnableBrightnessControl=1"
EndSection
```

to `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/10-nvidia-brightness.conf` as was [suggested in this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/812734/macbook-pro-backlight-control-not-working-on-ubuntu-16-04/1277326#1277326).

None of those solutions have worked for me, but I also haven't find any working solutions for my particular GPU or an Ubuntu Version above 20.

I am quite new to Linux in general and also this forum. Therefore I apologize in advance should there be some easy fix or whether I have overlooked one of many questions with the correct solution.

Answer (score 0):

I put

`sudo setpci -v -H1 -s 00:01.00 BRIDGE_CONTROL=0`

manually into the terminal and it worked!

The problem was, that [starting with Ubuntu 18.04 LTS there is no `/etc/rc.local` by default and creating one manually is not recommended](https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/rc.local/). Instead, I used [`@reboot` in `/etc/crontab`](http://geekstuff.org/2018/06/24/how-to-run-a-command-on-startup-in-ubuntu/) to execute the command on startup:

```
orkhans@matrix:~$ cat /etc/crontab
# /etc/crontab: system-wide crontab
# Unlike any other crontab you don't have to run the `crontab'
# command to install the new version when you edit this file
# and files in /etc/cron.d. These files also have username fields,
# that none of the other crontabs do.
SHELL=/bin/sh
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
# m h dom mon dow user  command
17 *  * * *  root    cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly
25 6  * * *  root  test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.daily )
47 6  * * 7  root  test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.weekly )
52 6  1 * *  root  test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.monthly )
#
@reboot root setpci -v -H1 -s 00:01.00 BRIDGE_CONTROL=0
```

Now it works fully and I can control my screen brightness as usual using `F1` and `F2`!